# Real Analysis - Subspace of separable metric spaces is closed and open

Tags: real-analysis

I am learning Real Analysis by myself and I ran across this question: "Show that every subspace of a separable metric space is separable"

Since a separable metric X contains a dense subset, X is closed. Using the above question, every subspace A of X is separable and is also closed. Since A is closed so the complement of A is open. But the complement of A is also a subspace of X, hence the complement of A is also separable and closed.

So I reach the conclusion that every subspace of a separable metric spaces is closed and open.

However, that conclusion is clearly wrong (R is separable but its singleton subset, let's choose 1, is only closed, not open).

Really appreciate if someone could show what is wrong with my reasoning.

Comment: The problem is that you are not being careful with what "closed" is. When you say that a set is closed, you have to specify in what space is it closed. Try to repeat the argument stating what is closed and where it is, you'll find that you can't reach this conclusion

Comment: Use second-countability.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "subspace of a seperable space is seperable" means that it is seperable with the subspace topology. In the subspace topology on A, A is closed and open, but it isn't in the topology on X.